# How to open an image in Android with when I have the uri?

Tags: android, image, android-intent

From my activity I open a Camera activity, take a picture and pass the uri back to my activity. Now I would like to just view the picture when I click on a button e.g. "result". This is what I do:

CameraActivity:

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {

    Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(
    Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    new ContentValues());
```

my mainActivity:

```
Intent pictureIntent = new Intent();
pictureIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pictureIntent.setData(task.getUri());

startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, PIC_REQ);
```

but I get the error:

```
05-05 00:17:41.800: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(748): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER dat=content://media/external/images/media/9 }
```

I've searched already a lot and I only found how to pick a picture from the gallery, but that's not what I want.

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Johannes